# Table concatenation in MSSQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case, I need to put some data into tables by month:

```
some_table_04
some_table_05
some_table_06
```

Is there a way to create a view like GBQ:

```
SELECT * FROM (TABLE_QUERY([some_table], "table_id like 'some_table_%'";
```

But in MSSQL Server 2008 R2?

Or, maybe, table inheritance like Postgres's

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(...);
CREATE TABLE some_table_04 (...) inherits (some_table);
CREATE TABLE some_table_05 (...) inherits (some_table);
CREATE TABLE some_table_06 (...) inherits (some_table);
```

And then work with base table?

Comment: I question whether creating separate tables for each month is even the right thing to be doing here.  Why are you going with that design decision?

Comment: Go for partitioned table go with https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manisblog/2009/01/17/easy-table-partitions-with-sql-server-2008/ approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table concatenation is achieved by `UNION ALL`:

```
select * from some_table_04
union all
select * from some_table_05
union all
select * from some_table_06
etc.
```

To do it dynamically, use this code:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000)
-- it will select all tables names some_table_**two digits** from your table,
-- I also assumed that these tables are in dbo schema
select @sql = @sql + 'select * from dbname.dbo.' + name + ' union all ' from [dbname].sys.tables
where name like 'some_table_[0-9][0-9]'

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: what about dynamic tables list generating? how it is possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You want to create list of names, tables or what?

Comment: If i will create new tables, is it possible to add in this query automaticaly?
Something like gbq query

Comment: Splitting tables into periods seems like a good idea until you work out what partitioning is. If you want to do this, use table partitioning.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid IMO, it would be easier to hold data in one table with `month` column or `date` column :) but I replied to OP's needs :)

Comment: It's true - you answered the question. I wasn't trying to undermine your answer, I just think the OP should take some advice.